# Get Cookie from another webApp

Tags: java, javascript, spring, setcookie

I have two web projects and one is only having the html and css...profiles in it, while the other is do request and response... I set cookie by using JavaScript, but I cannot get the cookie in the controller. Why is that?  Maybe it is because of a cross-domain problem， but how do I resolve that?

Comment: Cookies can be shared only through subdomains/domains but not cross domain. So in other words. `google.com` can share cookies with `mail.google.com`, but `google.com` cannot share with `yahoo.com`.

Comment: When I visit html page, use this URL:localhost:8080/noteweb/login.html and send request by ajax to localhost:8080/noteserver/check/checklogin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the looks of it, you have two different servers running, you will have the servers set up like this:

```
ServerA/login
ServerB/checkLogin
```

With that being said, I would recommend you do the following:

```
ServerA/login POSTS to ServerB/checkLogin 

{
    username: "bluejamesbond",
    password: "j3sgf45A3e3w"
}

ServerB/checkLogin responds with

{
    err : "0",
    accesscode : "CNXK" // will be invalid after say around 1 hour
}
```

ServerA stores this info into a cookie, then the next time ServerA needs to get content, it can do the following.

```
ServerA/homepage POSTS to ServerB/content
{
    type : "profile-info",
    accesscode : "CNXK",
    user : "bluejamesbond"
}
```

ServerB returns data if the `request.body.user == serverB.getUserByAccessCode(accesscode)`